# Objectlistview tooltip string padding

Tags: c#, objectlistview

i want my olv show tooltip when user hover a row and i want to format output string as a table.

Here is my code:

```
args.Title = "Danh sách sản phẩm";
HoaDon hoadon = args.Model as HoaDon;
args.StandardIcon = ToolTipControl.StandardIcons.Info;
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var chitiet in hoadon.DSChiTietHD)
{
     str.AppendLine();
     str.Append(chitiet.SanPham.MaSP.ToString().PadRight(10));
     str.Append(chitiet.SanPham.TenSP.PadRight(50));
     str.Append(chitiet.SoLuong.ToString().PadRight(10));
}
args.Text = str.ToString();
```

but here is the result:

[image]

I'dont know what happened with 2nd column. Please help!

Comment: Its probably because you are not using a Mono-Space font. The "space" char is much smaller than the "u". Naturally, the padding only considers the number of chars, not the width. Change the font to "Courier" for example, that should fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem fixed!

Comment: Nice. I will post this as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because you are not using a Mono-Space font. The "space" char is much smaller than the "u". Naturally, the padding only considers the number of chars, not the width. Change the font to "Courier" for example, that should fix it.